# Панибратство и амикошонство

Tags: лексикон, выбор-слова

Не так давно я встретил новое для себя слово **амикошонство**.

Словарь его определяет так:

> Чрезмерная фамильярность, бесцеремонность в обращении под видом
>   дружеского.

Мне это определение очень напомнило другое более распространенное слово: **панибратство**.

Его словари определяют так:

> Непочтительное, фамильярное обращение с тем, кто требует уважительного
>   отношения, со старшим.

В чем между ними оттеночная разница?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Панибратство* is a borrowing from Polish *panie bracie*, meaning "Mr. brother".

*Амикошонство* is a borrowing from French *ami cochon* which is a contraction of *amis comme cochons* ("friends like pigs"). This means "friends so close that they can deny social norms in communication between them (and behave like pigs)".

Semantically, the two mean the same: undesired familiarity. However, the former is widely used, while the latter is perceived as a high-style, inkhorn word.

Comment: By the way, isn't it a good style to place answer in same language that used by questioner?

Comment: @DmitryIlukhin: I want my answers to be read and understood by as many people as possible, including those who learn Russian.

Answer (score 3):

Basing on the quoted definitions alone, one could say `амикошонство` is when you're supposed to act like a friend to a person, but are abusing this right of yours (e.g. abusing your classmates while passing this off as friendly jokes), whereas `панибратство` is when you're not even supposed to appear like an equal to a person (e.g. you're greeting your teacher in a way you would greet your peer).

The above is a pure speculation of mine.

(For you non-native speakers: you will *never* hear `амикошонство` from anyone in Russia, unless you're being told [a joke](http://www.anafor.ru/other/quoting.htm).)

Comment: I saw "амикошонство" in a blog. And there was a remark in the comments that she (who wrote that comment) had used this word recently with a friend of hers. I personally don't use it now, but it may be not so with the other people.

Comment: @ovgolovin Yes, a joke plus the people who specifically use such words to appear... mmm... educated? Sophisticated? I'm not sure. My point was, this word is not a part of common vocabulary, to a degree where vast majority of native speakers would not even recognise it.

Comment: No, there wasn't that she had used this word as a joke (I took it as she was serious using it). As regards showing off with using such words, I don't believe in it being a good way of asserting oneself, because no one will tolerate such showing off and language is just a means of transferring the idea, so there is no use of using such words if they don't help to get your idea across.

Comment: амикошонство is a rare word, never seen in colloquial speech.